# Excel: Sum duplicates values only once and only on visible cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the following **FILTERED** table :

```
TYPE    NUM
A       3
A       3
A       3
B       5
B       5
```

I need to find the sum of column `NUM` without including the duplicate values.
I currently have the following solution based on another post:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6/COUNTIFS(A2:A6,A2:A6))`

In this case, the result is `8`, which is correct when no filters have been applied.

Now if I filter the column to show only **A** in `TYPE`, it will still show me `8`. The issue I am having is I need the sum to be adjusted based on what is visible. After applying the filter to show only **A**, I should be getting `3` and if I filter to show **B** only I should get `5`. I've tried `AGGREGATE` and `SUBTOTAL` and haven't gotten anywhere.

Is there a way to adjust the above formula to **VISIBLE** cells only?

Thanks,

Comment: So why not use SUMIFS() with the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's a rather complicated formula involving both `SUMPRODUCT()`, `SUBTOTAL()` and `OFFSET()`. More information [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria)

To implement this to your situation you would get:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6/COUNTIFS(A2:A6,A2:A6))*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B6)-MIN(ROW(B2:B6)),0))))
```

Another option would be (in your case if values for each criteria is the same)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6<>A3:A7)*(B2:B6)*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B6)-MIN(ROW(B2:B6)),0))))
```

[image]

In my example I'll filter out both A and B

[image]

A formula to be used on dynamic ranges would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))/COUNTIFS(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))))*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))-MIN(ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))),0))))
```

Comment: Hi! Can the formula be adjusted for a flexible range? In my original excel file, I have 1000's of lines and roughly 50 columns and the number of lines will vary day to day. I tried adjusting the ranges from `A2:A6` to `A2:A` but that doesn't seem to work. If not, I can always use VBA to workaround this.

Comment: Sure if you want to apply the 'uggly' `INDIRECT()` you could try: `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B))/COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A)),INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A))))*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B)))-MIN(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B:B)))),0))))`

Comment: @hisoka, ill also put another, less volatile, function in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, try this:

[image]

The drop down validation picks either A or B, but you can change that.
The formula is :

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B6,A2:A6,D2)/COUNTIFS(A2:A6,D2)
```

Edit, based on re-reading the question, I think this might be closer:

[image]

Comment: ++ For the simple solution if OP needs to just filter on 1 criteria :). I was overthinking things. Though more criteria can be involved.